# Can't access Tomcat using IP address

Tags: tomcat, localhost

I'm running a Tomcat 5.5 instance (port 8089) on Windows 7.

The server runs correctly if I open http://localhost:8089/ but it gives me an error (Connection refused) on http://192.168.1.100:8089/

I thought it was a firewall issue, so I disabled it, but I still have no luck.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to make Tomcat listen to 192.168.1.100 address also.

If you want it to listen to all interfaces (IP-s) just remove "address=" from Connector string in your configuration file and restart Tomcat.

Or just use your IP to listen to that address address=192.168.1.100 in the Connector string

Comment: What if you do not have the address configured?

Answer (score 29):

You need allow ip based access for tomcat in server.xml, by default its disabled.
Open server.xml search for "

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Here add a new attribute ***useIPVHosts="true"*** so it looks like this,

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443"
           useIPVHosts="true" />
```

Now restart tomcat, it should work

Comment: with tomcat7, for me to have it working (I mean allowing access from the outside with IP address), I have to also add `resolveHosts="true"` in <Valve ... /> at the end of the sever.xml file

Comment: My tomcat is in localhost, and a docker container wants to connect it. For the container, tomcat's IP address is 192.168.0.1:8080, but even after updating the above file, the connection is refused.

Answer (score 17):

If you are not able to access tomcat from remote, there might be reason that taken port is not open in your machine. Suppose you have taken 8081 port.

On Your windows machine:

Open Control panel-> windows Firewall-> Advance setting->Inbound Rules

Create a new rule: mention Port

[image: Picture1]

Configure your port and then shutdown and start your tomcat and it will be accessible from remote as well.

That port issue majorly comes in AWS machines.

If it is still not working then please check with your administrator that selected port is open for public access or not, if not then open it.

Answer (score 16):

If you are trying to access your web app which is running on apache tomcat server,
it might be working perfect while you are trying to use it on
    http://localhost:8080/
, it will not work same if you are trying to access it on your mobile device browser for ex. chrome using
    http://192.168.x.x:8080/ 
so if you want to access via ip address on your remote/mobile device , do following settings

1. Open server.xml file.
2. Change

   ```
   <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080"protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
   ```

to.

```
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0" />
```

3. Save the file
4. Stop and restart the server
5. Now access on your mobile device using ip address http://192.168.1.X:8080/

You are good to go.

Comment: This saved my day.

Comment: Glad to know that. 

Answer (score 12):

New versions of application servers removed the ability of binding to your entire network interface and limited it just to the local interface (localhost). The reason being was for security. From what I know, Tomcat and JBoss implement the same security measures.

If you want to bind it to another IP you can explicitly set it in your connector string:

- Tomcat: `address="192.168.1.100"`
- JBoss: you pass in a `-b 192.168.1.100` as a command line.

Just remember that binding `0.0.0.0` allows anyone access to your box to access that server. It will bind to all addresses. If that is what you want, then use 0.0.0.0, if it isn't then specify the address you would like to explicitly bind instead.

Just make sure you understand the consequences binding to all addresses (0.0.0.0)

Comment: sure, no problem, it's just a development server

Comment: where is the address="0.0.0.0" specified?  command line? xml file ??

Comment: ok I found it in the server.xml.  But 0.0.0.0 is not binding all ports as expected  "http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080"

Answer (score 3):

No solution mentioned above was solved my problem. My problem was different.

First check is your port is disabled in firewall.
Go to `Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advance Settings -> Inbound Rules` and see any port is blocked.

A sample image is below:

[image]

If so then you can unblock the port by following steps:

Step 1:

[image]

Here you can see that the port is blocked.

[image]

Step 2: `Allow the connection -> Apply -> Ok`.

[image]

That's solved my blocked problem. Happy coding :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Firewalls are often the problem in these situations. Personally, the Mcafee enterprise firewall was causing this issue even for requests within the network.

Disable your firewalls or add a rule for tomcat and see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all answers. For me it was a different issue. I had to set my wireless network to "private". I only need tomcat for network internal use. For some reason although firewall rule was set to allow for all, it does not allow access from within the same network if set to public.

Changing settings in server.xml were not needed in this usecase.

Answer (score 1):

To be accessible via IP (1.2.3.4) and hostname (localhost), I changed the `Engine` line in `server.xml` to

```
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" Host="1.2.3.4">
```

using Apache Tomcat/9.0.58 (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Check your windows-firewall feature in control panel. Outbound and inbound port should allow port 8089. (or write a new rule for this- Right hand side, actions - new rules.) it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem on Amazon windows EC2 instance ( Windows Server 2012 R2 ) 
Then I figured out , it was local windows firewall preventing it . 
I opened port 80 ( defined port for website ) using windows Firewall with Advance Security .

It resolved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

Very strange because the firewall caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall cause issue after  uninstalling Oracle JDK and installing OpenJDK on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8 not access on other machine after this.

Follow below path to add new rule

```
 --> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security on Local Computer
 --> Inbound Rule 
 -->Add New Rule 
      with specific port you have required for Tomcat application.
```