# how to just use IP and port to visit my servlet？

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I want to just use IP and port to access my servlet. 
Mapping is like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>yidong</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.dc.spdb.core.BFWebServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yidong</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/yidong</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: and what problems are you expecting? can't you just `http://IP:PORT/yidong` ?

Comment: Yes.That's a normal way ,but other people just want the unusual way.

Comment: Already solved.Just replace the stuff under ROOT using my own servlet,then I can access my servlet use IP:port

Answer (score 0):

You need allow ip based access for tomcat in server.xml, by default its disabled. Open server.xml search for "

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Here add a new attribute useIPVHosts="true" so it looks like this,

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443"
           useIPVHosts="true" />
```

Now restart tomcat, it should work

-- from [Can't access Tomcat using IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.My problem is not I couldnt aceess Tomcat using IP address.Usually we type IP:port ,we get that page with cat.Now I want use IP:port ,directly get my servlet yidong.