# Unable to Bind IP to Tomcat on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, tomcat7

When i access my tomcat from browser by localhost:8080 it works.
but when i try to access it through an IP does not work (for ex 192.168.1.250:8080).

it works fine on windows XP but not on Windows 7.

I search for it a lot but not getting proper solution, please help me out of this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't access Tomcat using IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to 192.168.1.250 must go through your router first.

You may need to open up port 8080 on your router, which you can find in the firewall/security settings.

Answer (score 0):

In server.xml (or wherever your Tomcat server configuration is) set address attribute for Connector to 192.168.1.250 (listens only on that address) or 0.0.0.0 (listens on all addresses, anyone with a connection to your machine can access the server).

Source: [Can't access Tomcat using IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address)