# Access Tomcat Through External Devices

Tags: tomcat

I am using Tomcat on my computer which is accessible through port 8080.
What I want is that I one should be enable to access my Tomcat server page using my Computer's IP Address. I've read many topics before but can't find a single one which could help me. I connect to the internet using Internet Sharing on my Windows Phone 8.1, so there are no router settings. Can somebody help me?

**I've read many topics before but no one seems to be helping me**

Comment: May be the tomcat config file is not correctly updated. Follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got what the actual problem is.
I should allow that port through firewall and everything works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Do "ipconfig" on command line tool, and copy the IPv4 address, it will be something like 192.168.70.200. Then in your call from any other device replace the "localhost" with this new address, like this "192.168.70.200:8080".

Comment: I did this. But it doesn't open. And what about external IP. Mine is 142.177.234.58

Comment: In the computer where tomcat is installed if you tap "localhost:8080" you should see the tomcat home page. If you see that, that your tomcat work well. Make sure that your local IP address is correct and try "142.177.234.58:8080" from an other laptop

Comment: Refer to my previous comment. I said it did not open

Comment: Your comment is not clear enough, You have to add more explanations and details. "did not open" is not sufficient to solve your problem. We are magicians to understand what happens with you.

Comment: I tried to open the tomcat server from another pc using my IP address, but it did not open