# Why can't remote access tomcat by 8080 port?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm having trouble accessing my web application, deployed on Tomcat, from another computer on my network. I can access the application through `localhost`, but can't do it from another PC on same LAN.

I have already stopped both `iptables` and `selinux`. I tried modifying  `setenv.sh` to set `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true"` just in case IPv6 was the problem, but none of these methods have solved my problem.

Why can't I access my web application remotely?

Comment: Have you tried looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address?

Comment: What does 'netstat -nl' return?

Comment: Please post your `<Connector>` configuration, and the complete `localhost` URL that actually works for you.