# Connect android device to Tomcat server running on my PC

Tags: java, android, tomcat, localhost

I am trying to connect with my device to the local Tomcat server by IP not with `localhost.` If I can work this out probably I will do it in Android too.

I know that I have to connect the device and PC to the same Wi-Fi.

I have a question: It's a problem if I connect to the internet with a proxy?

For example http://localhost:8080/create it's working on my PC when I deploy my app.

I tried to set Windows Firewall off or to create a new Rule(Inbound Rules) for `port 8080` but it didn't work for me. When I tried to connect to the server from my PC using the IP(I got it from `cmd -> ipconfig IPv4`) it did't work(192.168.0.101:8080/create).

I read many post on stack about this even tried to add a new environment variable for JAVA ( `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` ). I did this in `cmd with the command: setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` and received SUCCESS: Specified value was saved. Even changed the server.xml in \Tomcat 9.0\conf. Here is my Connector:

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               address="0.0.0.0"/>
```

I can access the server in the emulator with this IP: 10.0.0.2:8080/create. How I do it now for devices??
What I am missing. Can you guide me step by step how to do it?

Comment: Can you check this solution here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address

Comment: Use the browser on your android device to test a connection. Would be quicker than an app you write and re-deploy

Comment: I know it. Maybe I modify the wrong server.xml file. Can I modify the Connector from Eclipse? Because I run the server at port 8080

Comment: My device is working fine. I access any link. But the problem is why I can't connect to the server only with localhost:8080 and not by 192.168.0.101?

Comment: Can you vote the post? Maybe I get more views and find the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to fix the problem:

My tomcat is embedded so I created a file in /resources named `application.properties` and added: `server.address=<http://192.168.0.101>` and turned off Firewall.

Good luck!