# Can't access tomcat 7 via ip address

Tags: apache, tomcat7, centos7

I installed tomcat on centos 7 with yum, but I can't access tomcat from another computer in network lan using local ip address (10.133.12.239:8080). I think I made mistake config some where but I don't know where.

This is my server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
     <!-- 
      <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
          -->


    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

This is my catalina.log:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
May 26, 2017 2:38:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 369 ms
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/examples
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 383 ms
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/sample
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/sample has finished in 178 ms
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 149 ms
May 26, 2017 2:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/manager
May 26, 2017 2:38:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 26, 2017 2:38:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 151 ms
May 26, 2017 2:38:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/docs
May 26, 2017 2:38:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 26, 2017 2:38:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 157 ms
May 26, 2017 2:38:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080"]
May 26, 2017 2:38:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 26, 2017 2:38:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1427 ms
```

This is my firewall:

```
[root@CPP00110064C conf]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp2s0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 1521/tcp 443/tcp 80/tcp 8080/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  sourceports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

This is current port is running:

```
[root@CPP00110064C conf]# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10853/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10632/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1521            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8113/tnslsnr
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1771/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1113/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3094/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20633           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8344/ora_d000_RNN11
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2362/master
tcp        0      0 10.133.12.239:25        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2362/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10632/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10632/java
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1113/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      3094/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2362/master
tcp6       0      0 :::8441                 :::*                    LISTEN      1201/macmnsvc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access Tomcat using IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address)

Comment: @Harald I tried follow that but still can't access.

Comment: Can you access from the same machine using the IP address?

Comment: @Harald yes i can access http://10.133.12.239:8080 but can't access from another computer.

Comment: SOLVED: Bypass proxy 10.*.*.* on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Bypass proxy 10.*.*.* on my computer.