# Share my local webapp project

Tags: java, web-applications, localhost

I have started doing work with spring/hibernate to make webapps with java. I have made a basic app which is running on my localhost:8080 and I was wondering if there was an easy way to make it visible to someone else so they can see and use the webpage from their machine.

Answer (score 0):

If They are on same network (ie a Home Network or Corporate Network) you just need to send them you ip and port (ie http://192.168.0.150:8080).

If you want to open your computer by the internet you need to setup you modem to open you 8080 port and need to discover you public IP ou contract a DDNS, like no-ip.

Maybe you can need to change some firewall configurations

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to configure firewall, port forward. you can try some dynamic dns service like  www.no-ip.com, dyn, duck dns, freedns etc.

they will create a public url which will forward.

however at application level you may still need to configure the access permission like white list ip or address to listen

[Can't access Tomcat using IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address)