# Not able to connect localhost with system ip

Tags: java, networking, system-administration

I have deployed my java web application using apache tomcact in my system through Eclipse. I can access the same page with

```
https://localhost:8080/Home.jsp
```

as well

```
https://mysystemip:8080/Home.jsp
```

But the same page is not able to connect 
`https://mysystemip:8080/Home.jsp` over the network through other systems. Previously it was working and now not. What issue causing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Tomcat server is only bound to your local network interface. You need to bind it to all interfaces for it to be available.

There is already a solution ([Can't access Tomcat using IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address)):

> Add address="0.0.0.0" to Connector string