# Connect to tomcat using IPaddress

Tags: windows, tomcat, ip-address

I have a tomcat 9.0 installation on a server running Windows 2012 R2.  I have been connecting to the Tomcat console and other pages using LOCALHOST i.e  and it works fine.  However when I try to connect using the IP address I have no connection to Tomcat i.e using http://25.189.XX.XXX:82

I have been following other advice including:  [Can't access Tomcat using IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address)

My Server.xml file has the following entry:

```
<Connector port="82" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8443"
address="0.0.0.0"
useIPVHosts="true"  />
```

The last two lines I've added from information on the previous link.

I'm initially trying to connect locally to avoid the firewall, although I have opened a TCP port in the firewall to try externally but this also fails.

Is there something else that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This remains a problem.  Is there anymore information I can provide that may point towards the source of the issue?