# Ubuntu EC2 Server not connecting to Public-IP port 8080 for Tomcat7 & GeoServer

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, timeout, tomcat7

We have a server running a Flask App, which uses GeoServer under Tomcat7 to serve map data internally to the App itself, and externally via WMS to authenticated users.

This was all working fine until after some minor code edit/reload, command-line updates/upgrades and reboot (including reboot from EC2 console) when things stopped working.

After a bit of digging and debugging, it seems as if all the elements of the system are working ok individually, but the crucial requests to Tomcat7 and GeoServer via port 8080 are not connecting and timeout (usually after around 2mins).

I’ve taken a look at lots of online help for similar problems and checked, implemented and tested several of the suggestions, but nothing seems to clear the blockage.

I’m no expert (though I’m learning lots in the process!) and I’ve tried all the obvious & recommended things as far as I can tell.

I now seem to be going round in circles (i.e. nowhere) on this, so any suggestions as to what I might try next would be most gratefully received.

**Background Info:**

- EC2 instance with Public and Private IPs, no Elastic IPs or Load Balancers
- Ubuntu Xenial 16.04, Apache 2.4.18, Tomcat7, GeoServer 2.11.0
- Security Group configured and applied to EC2 instance with rules as follows:

  ```
  INBOUND RULES
  Type             Protocol   Port Range  Source
  HTTP             TCP        80          0.0.0.0/0
  HTTP             TCP        80          ::/0
  Custom TCP Rule  TCP        8080        x.x.x.x/32
  Custom TCP Rule  TCP        5432        x.x.x.x/32
  SSH              TCP        22          x.x.x.x/32
  Custom TCP Rule  TCP        443         0.0.0.0/0
  Custom TCP Rule  TCP        443         ::/0

  OUTBOUND RULES
  Type             Protocol   Port Range  Destination
  All traffic      All        All         0.0.0.0/0
  ```
- Domain name resolves Ok to the Public IP
- Firewall disabled - *sudo ufw status* returns 'Status: inactive'
- Can SSH into server from PuTTY
- Can access GeoServer Web Admin from browser using http://Public-IP:8080/geoserver/web/
- Checked [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/390840/how-does-one-get-tomcat-to-bind-to-ipv4-address) and updated /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh to add the following:

  ```
  JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Ad=true "
  ```
- Checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address) and updated /etc/tomcat7/server.xml to make the Connector string:

  ```
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
         connectionTimeout="20000"
         URIEncoding="UTF-8"
         redirectPort="8443"
         address="0.0.0.0"
         useIPVHosts="true" />
  ```
- Checked what’s listening on different ports using netstat:

  ```
  root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/var/log/apache2# netstat -ltnpa | grep -i --colour LISTEN
  tcp    0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1438/sendmail: MTA:
  tcp    0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1437/java
  tcp    0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1208/sshd
  tcp    0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1350/postgres
  tcp    0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1438/sendmail: MTA:
  tcp    0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1437/java
  tcp6   0      0 :::80                   :::*            LISTEN      1456/apache2
  tcp6   0      0 :::22                   :::*            LISTEN      1208/sshd
  tcp6   0      0 :::5432                 :::*            LISTEN      1350/postgres
  tcp6   0      0 :::443                  :::*            LISTEN      1456/apache2
  ```

**Problems Observed**

Debug reveals that the Flask app sends well-formed requests to http://Public-IP:8080/geoserver/roar/wms?... but the call to urllib2.urlopen(req) throws exception ‘[Errno 110] Connection timed out’, which is reported with abort(404).

If I take the request string (with Public-IP) and paste it in the browser it works. Note this is http:// and not https:// - not sure if this is significant - see below for notes on using https://

If I try cURL from the command line using the Public-IP, I get timeout messages:

```
    connect to Public-IP port 8080 failed: Connection timed out
    * Failed to connect to Public-IP port 8080: Connection timed out
    * Closing connection 0
```

If I try cURL from the command line using the localhost, e.g. to Tomcat7 on port 8080, it works…

```
    $ curl -v localhost:8080/
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
    > GET / HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost:8080
    > User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
    > Accept: */*
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    < Accept-Ranges: bytes
    < ETag: W/"1896-1493801565000"
    < Last-Modified: Wed, 03 May 2017 08:52:45 GMT
    < Content-Type: text/html
    < Content-Length: 1896
    < Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 09:39:46 GMT
    <
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>It works !</h1>
    etc…….
```

If I try cURL from the command line using the Private-IP, e.g. to Tomcat7 on port 8080, it works…

```
    $ curl -v Private-IP:8080/
    *   Trying Private-IP...
    * Connected to Private-IP (Private-IP) port 8080 (#0)
    > GET / HTTP/1.1
    > Host: Private-IP:8080
    > User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
    > Accept: */*
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    < Accept-Ranges: bytes
    < ETag: W/"1896-1493801565000"
    < Last-Modified: Wed, 03 May 2017 08:52:45 GMT
    < Content-Type: text/html
    < Content-Length: 1896
    < Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 09:42:30 GMT
    <
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>It works !</h1>
    etc…….
```

If I simply try connecting to port 8080 from the browser using http:// with either the domain name or the Public-IP, I get the Tomcat7 index.html ‘It works!’ response.

If I try the same using https://, I get the following from Mozilla…

```
   Secure Connection Failed
   An error occurred during a connection to Public-IP:8080. SSL received a record that
   exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
       The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data
       could not be verified.
```

and from IE (suggested settings *are* turned on)…

```
    This page can’t be displayed
    Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to
    https://Public-IP:8080  again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an
    unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered
    secure. Please contact your site administrator.
```

and from Chrome…

```
    This site can’t provide a secure connection
    Public-IP sent an invalid response.
    Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
    ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Flask app and GeoServer run on the same EC2 server, they should communicate between each other via `localhost` not Private-IP or Public-IP

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Peter, that makes sense. I guess the Public-IP in the config file (loaded from the repo) created the confusion.