# Unable to access tomcat application using DNS

Tags: java, dns, tomcat7

I have a Windows 2012 server which I am using to host some .NET and Java applications. Java applications will be deployed on Tomcat 7 and .NET on IIS. I have also got a DNS so that the applications are accessible over internet. However the applications hosted on tomcat are not accessible from internet. What I'm doing is:

- Run Tomcat on port 80

  1. Access application using localhost  - Accessible
  2. Access application using DNS  - Not Accessible, I get count not reach to server error
- Stop tomcat and start IIS on port 80

  1. Access application using localhost  - Accessible
  2. Access application using DNS  - Accessible

As the IIS applications on same port are accessible over internet, I feel that this is not a firewall issue. I did go through most of the questions here, tried all the options but none helped.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address ==> Add `address="0.0.0.0"` in `Connector` part of `server.xml`

Comment: I already have added the address="0.0.0.0" in my server.xml.