# tomcat stuck while installing dspace on Virtual Private Server

Tags: java, tomcat, vps, tomcat9, dspace

I've finished installing dspace but having problems can't call it with ip public.

when i check my tomcat with "sudo systemct1 status tomcat"

```
tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-12-24 13:45:03 WIB; 2min 27s ago
  Process: 20651 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20658 (java)
    Tasks: 32 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 104.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
           └─20658 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.pr

Dec 24 13:45:03 srv5.ugj.ac.id systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
Dec 24 13:45:03 srv5.ugj.ac.id startup.sh[20651]: Tomcat started.
Dec 24 13:45:03 srv5.ugj.ac.id systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
```

here is my tomcat.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-server -Xms384M -Xmx512M'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx7168m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
ReadWritePaths=/dspace
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

please help me

Comment: Tomcat started so that is not the problem (or it crashed?). I don't think tomcat by default listens to all the interfaces, you need to set address in the server.xml Then you have to check if it really listens (netstat -tnlp | grep 8080) and then you need to make sure you are not firewalling.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246127/cant-access-tomcat-using-ip-address

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.